# screen a serial get could not find a PTY Error

Tags: macos, display, serial

I insert the serial-USB convertor into my Mac.

and under the `/dev` I find the `tty.wchusbserial1410`.

but when I use `screen` to connect it:

```
screen /dev/tty.wchusbserial1410 9600
```

there get error:

> Sorry, could not find a PTY.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, I find the solution, there are a screen process not close normality.

So, in the Activity Monitor I closed it, then re-start the screen, it works.

Comment: To kill from terminal you can. First re-attach from terminal run `screen -ls`. Then reconnect to session with `screen -r 49627` (where the number is the ID found with `screen -ls`). Then kill it properly with `cmd + a` and then press `k` for kill and `y` for yes.

Comment: Or after `screen -ls` run `screen -XS 49627 quit` (where the number is the ID found with screen -ls).

Comment: @TimNode thanks a lot, it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

In my case simply unplugging the device from the computer (i.e., USB to serial adapter) then plugging back in again cleared the issue.

Comment: Likely, resetting the unit would have worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and I attempted a number of different solutions. Just wanted to share what made it work for me.

**Problem**

Tried to use the screen program to connect my lab PC to a Raspberry PI via the USB ports and an RS232 cable.

Ran the command screen /dev/ttyUSB0

Got the following error messages in quick succession.

"Cannot access line '/dev/ttyUSB0 for r/w: permission denied"

"Couldn't find a PTY"

**Attempted solutions**

1. I tried to look in the activity monitor to see if there are any processes running, and there was none. So this was not the problem.
2. Tried to change the /dev/ptmx file permissions

Ran the command ls -l /dev/ptmx

**Output** crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 5, 2 "datetime" /dev/ptmx

So it looked like the permission were already set. So this was not the problem either.

3. Tried to mount /dev/pts by running

sudo mount devpts /dev/pts -t devpts -o mode=620

I got the message that the mounting was already done. Move on.

4. Finally found this idea of adding to the dialout group looking at this post.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/58119/changing-permissions-on-serial-port

Ran the command - sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

Restarted the computer and voila, it worked. Was able to use screen program to make the connection.

Spend a few hours to figure this out. Hope this helps someone out. Peace.